# Why is $\hom_R(k,R)=0$ for a field $k$ and $R=k[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to compute $\operatorname{Ext}_R^i(k,R)$, and can't seem to understand why this homomorphism group is trivial. It seems to me that the two maps

> $\varphi:1\to 0$
>   $\psi:1\to 1$

are both valid members of the group. I am not exactly sure what the defined action of $R$ on $k$ given is, which may be part of the problem. If it helps, the value of $\operatorname{Ext}_R^i$ is trivial for all $i>0$ except for $\operatorname{Ext}_R^2(k,R)\cong k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have $\psi : 1 \mapsto 1$, assume that $k[x,y]$ acts on itself in the natural way through multiplication and let $a := x\cdot 1$. As we don't know the action of $k[x,y]$ on $k$, all we can say is that $a \in k$. Then $\phi(a) =  \phi(x\cdot 1 ) = x\phi(1) = x$. But $a$ is an element of $k$ and thus $\phi(a) = \phi(a \cdot 1) = a$, a contradiction.

edit: This of course works as soon as you send $1$ to anything but zero, thus showing that there is only the trivial homomorphism.